# Angular 2 definition file

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I have a custom gantt library, that is based on d3. It's written in normal javascript. Now I want to add it to my Angular 2 App. I allready installed D3 via npm and added a type file as well as the gantt chart to the node_modules but I get the following error message:

```
__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4_d3__.gantt is not a function
```

I think it's because of wrong usage of export and definition file. But I have no idea how to solve it.

node_modules/d3/index.js:

```
export {version} from "./build/package";
export * from "d3-array";
.
.
.
export * from "d3-gantt";
```

node_modules/d3-gantt/index.js:

```
export default gantt;

function gantt()
{
    // a lot of code
    return gantt
}
```

node_modules/@types/d3/index.d.ts:

```
export as namespace d3;
export * from 'd3-array';
.
.
.
export * from 'd3-gantt';
```

node_modules/@types/d3-gantt/index.d.ts:

```
export function gantt(): any;
```

src/app/AppComponent.ts

```
buildGantt(){
...
import * as d3 from 'd3'
d3.gantt().taskTypes(taskNames).taskStatus(taskStatus).selector('#d3Chart') //here i get the error
...
}
```

Comment: I have similar issue, did you resolve it?

Comment: @David I postet my solution as I remembered

Answer (score 0):

- add a javascript folder in app directory
- place your d3-gantt folder in there
- besides the normal code add index.d.ts with the line: `export function gantt(): any;`
- in your app.components.ts add `import { gantt } from "./javascript/d3-gantt";`
- set     `"allowJs":true,` in tsconfig.json

worked like this for me